# Is there a word beyond reflection, that is 'using the past mistakes to learn for the future?'

Tags: single-word-requests

Currently writing a thesis, and a thesaurus has not yielded any positive results. If avoidable, I would love to stop repeating 'reflect', 'reflection' etc, in my paper.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It really depends on the nature of the "mistake".  Is there remorse and contrition? *It was a mistake to give you so much responsibility when you were so young.* Or is it merely a practical kind of learning, such as "I won't take that route at rush hour again."

Answer (score 1):

If *memory serves* me, "***reflection***" does not necessarily mean drawing from the past. You might consider "**self-correction (or self-correcting)**" to describe learning from one's mistakes. Words along the line of being reminded (*remembrance*), could be "**retrospection**", "**recollection**", or "**hindsight**" as possible noun choices for "*reflection*". They have verb/adj/idiomatic forms as well. Their meanings all *reflect* the idea of drawing on past knowledge for present application (not necessarily past mistakes). From these, you will probably find other possibilities.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-correction

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/reflection

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/retrospection

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recollection

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hindsight